# Python - How do I get the defined variable from one function to another function?

Tags: python

I have simplified it to this:

```
def hang():
    p = 1
    while p == 1:
        gameinput = input("Please select a gamemode, Type [1] for one player or Type [2] for two player: ")
        if gameinput == "2":
            def two_player_word():
                print("2")
        elif gameinput == "1":
            def one_player_word():
                print("1")

def hangman():
    if gameinput == "2":
        word = two_player_word()
    elif gameinput == "1":
        word = one_player_word()
    print("Word")

def main():
    gamerestart = 1
    while gamerestart == 1:
        print()
        print("Would you like to play again?")
        gameoverinput = input("Press [1] to play again, Press [2] to exit program. ")
        if gameoverinput == "1":
            for i in range(0, 25):
                print()
            hangman()
        elif gameoverinput == "2":
            print("Thank you for playing, goodbye....")
            time.sleep(2)
            quit()
        else:
            print("Invaild option.")

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I had previously defined gameinput in the 'hang()' it collects the user input and so on.
My problem is in the 'hangman()' I need gameinput again to make the variable word (its made so a user can either make a word (two_player_word) or one player when it generates a random word (one_player_word()

It works perfectly without gameinput being in a function but after the player either wins or loses I want it to let the user decide if they want to change gamemode or not as shown in main().

There is a lot more code but figured it would be easier to try figure out the problem using just this.

Comment: Please fix the indentation, this matters in Python. Return variables from `hang()` and store them when you call it, then pass the returned value to `hangman()` as an argument.

Comment: As written, with assumptions about correct indentation, `hang()` will never return because `p` is never any value but `1`. Also, the nested functions (`one_player_word()` and `two_player_word()`) are unnecessary and have no effect.

Comment: Rather than defining a flag like p = 1 or gamerestart = 1 try using while True: and using break to exit the loop, it makes the code more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the `gameinput` from `hang` into `hangman` as an argument.

```py
def hang():
    while True:
        gameinput = input("Please select a gamemode, Type [1] for one player or Type [2] for two player: ")
        if gameinput not in ("1", "2"):
            continue
        hangman(gameinput)
        break


def hangman(gameinput):
    if gameinput == "2":
        word = two_player_word()
    elif gameinput == "1":
        word = one_player_word()
    print("Word")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems that cause your code to fail (besides indentation).

1. You are defining nested functions (`one/two_player_word`) which you then try to call from outside the function (where they are not defined). You can change this by defining the functions outside the function `hang()`.
2. `hangman()` uses the gameinput variable but it's not defined nor provided. You can change this by adding it as a parameter to the function call.

Your adjusted code could work like this:

```
import time

def one_player_word():
  print("1")

def two_player_word():
  print("2")

def hang():
  p = 1
  while p == 1:
      gameinput = input("Please select a gamemode, Type [1] for one player or Type [2] for two player: ")
      if gameinput == "2":
        two_player_word()
      elif gameinput == "1":
        one_player_word()

def hangman(gameinput):
    if gameinput == "2":
        word = two_player_word()
    elif gameinput == "1":
        word = one_player_word()
    print("Word")

def main():
    gamerestart = 1
    while gamerestart == 1:
        print()
        print("Would you like to play again?")
        gameoverinput = input("Press [1] to play again, Press [2] to exit program. ")
        if gameoverinput == "1":
            for i in range(0, 25):
                print()
            hangman(gameoverinput)
        elif gameoverinput == "2":
            print("Thank you for playing, goodbye....")
            time.sleep(2)
            quit()
        else:
            print("Invaild option.")

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```